# Est-ce qu'un pronom ou un verbe peuvent être noyau du groupe nominal?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, noms

Je rencontre des définitions différentes du noyau du groupe de nom. Dans certaines sources on dit que le noyau doit être absolument un nom, dans d'autres on dit qu'un pronom peut l'être, dans les troisièmes on dit que même qu'un verbe à l'infinitif peut l'être.

J'ai beaucoup de confusions à ce sujet.

Est-ce que quelqu'un peut aider à clarifier le sujet ?

Answer (score 1):

Réponse officieuse, il semblerait qu'il y ait deux définitions du groupe nominal, 'ce qui vient avant le verbe' (dans une phrase affirmative) et 'un groupe de mots centrés autour d'un nom'. La première permet les pronoms et un peu les verbes ('Rire est le propre de l'homme', avec rire pour 'l'acte de rire'). La deuxième, apparemment plus courante, n'autorise pas les pronoms car elle est centrée autour d'un nom, mais est remplaçable par un pronom.

Comment: Je préfère la réponse de Laure. La règle "le groupe nominal est ce qui est remplaçable par un pronom" permet de décider facilement.

Comment: Ne mélange-t-on pas la fonction et les classes de mots? 'Ce qui vient avant le verbe' c'est plutôt une definition du sujet ou groupe de sujet. C'est clair qu'un pronom ou infinitif peut la jouer. Cependant, le nom, pronom et verbe restent des classent des mots différents.

Comment: Oui, j'avoue ne pas savoir si il y a une définition officielle du groupe nominal, ou si c'est un lieu commun que partagent les livres de grammaire dans le but de communiquer en français (auquel cas il peut varier). L'académie française semble l'utiliser dans le sens 'mots autour d'un nom' http://www.academie-francaise.fr/dire-ne-pas-dire/courrier-des-internautes (10 juin 2014). Je me demande si la confusion ne vient pas de "nominal/nominatif", déclinaison latine du sujet.

Comment: @Lecteur12 On ne peut pas définir un mot par sa place (avant ou après) autour du verbe. La place peut varier selon le type de phrase, mais la fonction et la classe du mot (qui sont deux choses bien distinctes) ne changeront pas si la phrase affirmative devient interrogative.

Comment: Euh, la c'est moi qui fait un abus de langage. Je pensais au francais comme langue SVO ( http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langue_SVO ).

Answer (score 0):

Je pense qu'il y a un consensus pour dire que

- le groupe nominal est **un groupe dont le noyau est un nom**,
- ainsi que pour dire que **le groupe nominal** – c’est-à-dire le nom noyau et les constituants qui l’accompagnent (déterminant, complément du nom) – **peut être remplacé par un pronom**.

Donc la question est de savoir si ce qui peut remplacer le nom est aussi considéré aussi comme pouvant être noyau du groupe nominal. Point que certaines grammaires effectivement ignorent. Ceci certainement parce que la notion de groupe nominal ne fait pas partie de la grammaire « traditionnelle »<sup>1</sup>.

L'article de wikipedia est hésitant :

> Seul un mot plein (ou **à la rigueur**<sup>2</sup>, un pronom) peut être le noyau d'un syntagme,

J'ai trouvé sur le site de l'école secondaire franco-ontarienne [Franco-Cité](http://www.francocite.ca) une explication destiné à des élèves de primaire qui me semble claire et très logique :

> puisque le PRONOM peut remplacer le nom, il peut aussi être un groupe nominal.

La *Banque de dépannage linguistique* du Québec dit que :

> Quelles que soient sa forme ou sa complexité, le GN peut être remplacé par un pronom. **La pronominalisation permet de délimiter le groupe nominal**<sup>1</sup>.
>   Ce que je comprends comme disant qu'un pronom est un groupe nominal.

[Français Facile](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-83972.php) est très explicite sur ce point :

> Le GN peut être formé [...] d'un pronom

Et donne comme exemple :

> **Je les lui** donnerai quand je **la** verrai.

La règle générale semble cependant de jouer autour de la notion d'« être » et  de « fonction ».

> Bien entendu, ces diverses fonctions peuvent être occupées par un nom seul ou son équivalent (pronom, infinitif-nom, adverbe de quantité nominalisé, etc.).
>   (rubrique « [groupe nominal](http://www.synapse-fr.com/manuels/GR_NOMI.htm) » du site de *Cordial*)

En ce qui concerne l'infinitif la question est, me semble-t-il plus simple, on dit que l'infinitif est la forme nominale du verbe<sup>3</sup>, et son emploi comme noyau du groupe nominal est plus évident.

Et tout est bien dit sur le site [Études Littéraires](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/infinitif.php#4) :

> L’infinitif est le centre d’un groupe ayant une fonction nominale

<sub>1.Voir par exemple ce qu'en dit *[La Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4321)* du Québec.</sub>
<sub>2. C'est moi qui souligne.</sub>
<sub>3. Voir encore  *La Banque de dépannage linguistique* du Québec sur les fonctions nominales de l'infinitif][4](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/infinitif.php#4).</sub>

Comment: Francocité est une école secondaire (franco-)ontarienne, pas une école primaire québécoise. Aussi, serait-ce possible d'avoir un lien vers le document PowerPoint qui ne force pas un téléchargement?

Comment: @Kareen Merci pour la précision, je vais rectifier. Je n'ai pas trouvé  le document accessible directement via sur une page html du site de l'école, si tu le trouves, je veux bien modifier. Il a été repris par d'autres "personnes" qui l'ont mis sur leur site avec la référence de l'école mais je ne trouve pas éthique de ne pas renvoyer au site de de dépôt original. Je modifie pour ne pas forcer le téléchargement mais en laissant la mention de l'école. Si tu vois comment faire mieux, je veux bien que tu me dises !

Comment: Je crois que dans certains grammaires on mélange la function et la classe des mots. Surtout, en utilisant des termes obscures comme GNs (groupe nominal sujet) ou "fonction nominale". On peut parler de la fonction sujet, complément etc. que le nom peut jouer, mais l'expression "fonction nominale" me semble une absurdité. Si le nom du groupe nominal est donné par la classe de son noyau (nom), je trouve illogique d'y emmeler le pronom et verbe sous pretexte qu'ils peuvent jouer la meme function du sujet. Le terme "groupe sujet" serait plus approprié, ne trouvez-vous pas?

Comment: @Lecteur12 Ce que tu dis est vrai pour certaines grammaires que je pourrais qualifier de « basiques » et autres sources amateurs sur internet. Ce n'est pas le cas pour les ouvrages scientifiques que j'ai sous la main, comme  *Le bon usage* (Grevisse) et la *Grammaire du français contemporain* (différents auteurs dont [Claire-Blanche Benveniste](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claire_Blanche-Benveniste?oldformat=true) et [Michel Arrivé](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Arriv%C3%A9?oldformat=true)).

Comment: @Lecteur12 Extraits de l'introduction du chapitre sur la phrase simple e la *Grammaire du français Contemporain* : « classe grammaticale : nom, pronom, adjectif, verbe, etc... Fonction fondamentales dites essentielles : sujet, objet, circonstancielle. Ces fonctions essentielles se déterminent par rapport à un verbe : elles forment le groupe verbal. Chacune de ces fonctions peut être remplie par un mot simple ou par un groupe de mot. À l'intérieur de ces groupes, on distingue aussi des fonctions accessoires; telles sont les fonctions épithète ou complément de nom » etc.